# GTK transition effects

Tags: gtk

i am just a beginner with gtk.
i have created some of the example of GTK with GTK+Glade.

but i want to do some transition effects (Animation) on my Widgets/Windows/Components
While they appear/disappear on screen.

how do we do it with GTK and Glade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean transition effects like windows fading in and dropdown lists animating, then the answer is you can't. These effects are the domain of the window manager. To get them you have to use a window manager with fancy effects, like [Compiz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz).

This also means that anyone using your application could be using any window manager, so you can't count on them seeing the same effects. That's why you can't program them in GTK.

Comment: Ok... the application i am trying out is for specific window manager.. and it will not be used anywhere else... so how should i start of with this? how should i get to know which window manager i my application is using? and it's API's for doing transition.

Answer (score 0):

Using compiz or in windows set the opacity of your Gtk window to increase using a timer, overriding the on_expose event.

Comment: That is exactely what I am trying (unsuccessfuly) do. Do you have any code with this `timer` trick?

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can do that using [Clutter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clutter_%28toolkit%29) and [Clutter-GTK](http://blogs.gnome.org/clutter/) wich integrates GTK inside Clutter.